# Jquery - Hide Radio buttons - But Make the image clickable to show a bigger image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Current HTML looks like this (I do not have any control over the HTML as its SAAS, so I can add only Jquery)

[image]

What I am trying to do is something like the following image. The problem is how to 
 (1) hide the hide buttons from the display (but it should be in the background, meaning I need to know what image was selected in the form). 
 (2) How to Pass the image name to  `<div class="Show-which-image-is-selected-here">` and change the source of that image.

[image]

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
              <div id="input-option257">               
              <div class="radio">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[257]" value="133">
                     <img src="black-50x50.JPG" alt="Black " class="img-thumbnail">                   
                    Black
                     </label>
                </div>
                                <div class="radio">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[257]" value="141">
                     <img src="white-50x50.jpg" alt="White " class="img-thumbnail">                   
                    White
                     </label>
                </div>
                                <div class="radio">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[257]" value="136">
                     <img src="light%20grey-50x50.JPG" alt="Light Gray " class="img-thumbnail">                   
                    Light Gray
                     </label>
                </div>

                 </div>
            </div>

            <div class="Show-which-image-is-selected-here">
            <img src="<BIGIMAGE-black-50x50.JPG" alt="Black " class="img-thumbnail">        
            </div>
```

**My jquery**

```
$('#input-option257').parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point 1: you can just do it with CSS or you can also do it in jQuery if you can use CSS

for point number 2 just change the `src` attribute for the `<img>` inside the `click()` event handler

This is a working snippet, note that I added Images:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $("input[type='radio']").style({display:none})
  $("img").click(function() {
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .find("input[type='radio']")
      .prop("checked", true);
    $(".Show-which-image-is-selected-here img").attr(
      "src",
      $(this).attr("src")
    );
  });
});
```

```css
input[type='radio'] {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div id="input-option257">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="option[257]" value="133">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=image+1" alt="Black " class="img-thumbnail"> Black
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="option[257]" value="141">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=image+2" alt="White " class="img-thumbnail"> White
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="option[257]" value="136">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=image+3" alt="Light Gray " class="img-thumbnail"> Light Gray
            </label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="Show-which-image-is-selected-here">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=image+3" alt="Black " class="img-thumbnail">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```